# Change account.template, based on record state - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

Suppose I have `model_1`, this model has a `state` Selection field, like, for example: `draft, started, progress, done`

This model, has a `line`, this `line` (or `One2many`) field, brings a `product` object.

On this `product` object, I've set these fields:

```
erp_common = fields.Many2one('account.account.template', string='ERP Common Account')
paper_suppl_pay_acc = fields.Many2one('account.account.template', string='Payment Account')
paper_suppl_stock_acc = fields.Many2one('account.account.template', string='Stock Account')
```

What I want, is, for example, I create a new record, on `model_1`, this record is on `draft` state, if on `draft` the `product` should use the `erp_common` selected `account.account.template`, now, I change the `model_1` state to `started`, the product automatically should use (or change for what matters) the `account.account.template` used to `paper_suppl_stock_acc`.

I hope I'm explaining myself properly.

Essentially, depending on  the `state` of `model_1` the product should use one different `account.account.template`.

It is somehow similar to when You specify an account for purchases or sales, so depending on which object You create, it uses that specific `account.account.template`, but this is kind of more dynamical.

Is there some example around I should look for?

Or better, do You know a way in such I could accomplish this?